# Pandas not working in AWS GLUE 4.0 version

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Pandas not working in AWS GLUE 4.0 version:-

I tried importing pandas in AWS Glue 4.0 but getting following error, pandas is working in AWS Glue 3.0 version but not in 4.0.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'**

Comment: Use glue 3 if you can.

Comment: I am using Delta 2.1.0 version with Spark3.3, and this version is supported by Glue 4.0 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this issue and have contacted AWS support about it. It appears that it is an AWS issue and is happening to anyone who uses it. They are currently working on a fix.